# Nagios SNMP v3 on HP Procurve 2910

Tags: snmp, nagios

I'm having trouble getting the check_snmp plugin to connect and return values. I'm running CentOS7, Nagios 4.0.8, check_snmp 2.0.3. While can snmpget and snmpwalk from the command line, check_snmp fails. Here are some examples...

**snmpget:**

```
# snmpget -v 3 -u myuser -x aes -X mypasswd -a md5 -A mypasswd -c Public -l AuthPriv 111.222.333.111 sysUpTime.0
```

...returns...

```
DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance = Timeticks: (10475998) 1 day, 5:05:59.98
```

**snmpwalk:**

```
# snmpwalk -v 3 -u myuser -x aes -X mypasswd -a md5 -A mypasswd -c Public -l AuthPriv 111.222.333.111 sysUptime
```

...returns...

```
DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance = Timeticks: (10473493) 1 day, 5:06:10.93
```

**check_snmp:**

```
 /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_snmp -H 111.222.333.111 -o sysUpTime.0 -P 3 -l AuthPriv -U myuser -A mypasswd -a md5 -X mypasswd -x aes
```

...returns...

```
External command error: Error in packet
Reason: authorizationError (access denied to that object)
Failed object: DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance
```

When I run check_snmp with verbose on, I get...

```
/usr/bin/snmpget -Le -t 1 -r 5 -m ALL -v 3 [authpriv] 156.128.2.250:161 sysUpTime.0
```

check_snmp is clearly not constructing the snmpget command with the args that are being passed to it. I'm at a loss for why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is a little different for check_snmp sec level. Try:

```
-L authPriv
```

instead of:

```
-l AuthPriv
```

You can confirm this by invoking the help of the plugin with -h:

```
./check_snmp -h 
check_snmp v2.0.3 (nagios-plugins 2.0.3)
...
-L, --seclevel=[noAuthNoPriv|authNoPriv|authPriv]
...
```

Comment: Stupid syntax!!! They use different arg labels just to mess us you don't they? ;) That did the trick.

Comment: Yes, i really don't see why it is like this. Plus, many snpm v3 scripts gues seclevel from the provided arguments